# how can i set two for loop in django template for send and receive chats?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

im trying to set receive and send message in django template with to for loop this is my views function:

```
@login_required
def message_form(request,id,slug,user_id):

    user2=request.user
    user_id=user_id
    user = get_object_or_404(User,id=user_id)
    msg = Message.objects.filter(sender=user)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,id=id,slug=slug)
    post2 = Post.objects.filter(user=post.user)
    inbox = Message.objects.filter(reciever=request.user)
    sentbox = Message.objects.filter(sender = request.user)
    message1 = Message.objects.filter(post = post ,sender=user,reciever=post.user).order_by('date')

    message2 = Message.objects.filter(post = post ,sender=post.user,reciever=user).order_by('date')

reverse=True))

    # if user_id == request.user.id:
    #    message2 = Message.objects.filter(post = post ,sender=post.user,reciever=user).order_by('date')
    # if post.user == request.user:
    #    message2 = Message.objects.filter(post = post ,sender=post.user,reciever=user).order_by('date')


form = MessageForm(request.POST or None )
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        # form.save()
        message = form.save(commit=False)
        if post.user == request.user:
           message.sender = post.user
           message.reciever = user
        else:
           message.sender = request.user
           message.reciever = post.user

        message.post = post
        message.post_user = post.user
        message.post_image = post.image1
        message.save()
        # text = form.cleaned_data['post']
        form =  MessageForm()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')

context={

 'post':post,
 'post2':post2,
 'inbox':inbox,
 'sentbox':sentbox,
 'form':form,
 'message1':message1,
 'user_id':user_id,
 'msg':msg,
 'message2':message2,

}


return render(request,'chat.html',context)
```

and this is the part of  template chat.html:

```
               <div class="border px-2 chat-box ">
                   {% for box in message1 %}
                       <div class=" my-4 border bg-light ">
                         <span class=" p-2 my-5">{{ box.msg_content }}</span><br>
                         <span class="date text-muted ">{{ box.whenpublished }}</span>
                       </div>
                   {% endfor %} 

                   {% for box2 in message2 %}
                      <div class=" border bg-danger"  style="" >
                         <span class="  p-2 my-5" >{{ box2.msg_content }}</span><br>
                         <span class="date text-muted">{{ box2.whenpublished }}</span>
                      </div>
                   {% endfor %}

                 </div>
```

when i send and receive message Each of them shows separately like this:

```
hello(user1)

how are you(user1)

hello(user2)

im fine thnaks(user2)
```

but i want when i send one message its show after receive message like this in my template

```
hello(user1)

hello(user2)

how are you(user1)

im fine thanks(user2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you understand the question well, but I think this problem needs to be solved in views.py

> views.py

```
import operator
from itertools import chain

def function(request):
    '''
    message1 = "call user1's message"
    message2 = "call user2's message"
    message = list(chain(message1, message2))
    message = sorted(message, key=operator.attrgetter('whenpublished', reverse=True)
    '''

    return render(requeset, "YOUR HTML FILE", {
      'message': message,
    }
```

> html

```
<div class="border px-2 chat-box ">
    {% for box in message %}
    <div class=" my-4 border bg-light ">
        <span class=" p-2 my-5">{{ box.msg_content }}</span><br>
        <span class="date text-muted ">{{ box.whenpublished }}</span>
    </div>
    {% endfor %} 
</div>
```

Comment: , i faced with this error attrgetter() does not take keyword arguments

Comment: thank you i changed 'whenpublished' to 'id' and now its work. now i want set some style for it for example i want show receive message in right of box and sent message in left and change the background color for each of them have you any idea in this case

Comment: @mehdi I haven't been able to see any comments since I was looking for a job. I hope the issue has been resolved.